# COUNT(*) Includes Null Values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) documentation states:

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL
>   values and duplicates.

How can you have a null value in a group? Can anyone explain the point they're trying to make?

Comment: If you look a little bit further up they've used better formulation: _"COUNT(*) returns the number of rows in a specified table without getting rid of duplicates. It counts each row separately. This includes rows that contain null values."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you, I missed that. That states things much more clearly.

Comment: I removed my comments because now that I re-read your question and your comment you're really asking "Why did Microsoft write such a bad explanation in the documentation". I don't know the answer to that question.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you have this table

**Table1:**

```
 Field1    Field2    Field3
 ---------------------------
   1         1         1
  NULL      NULL      NULL
   2         2        NULL
   1         3         1
```

Then

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(Field1), COUNT(Field2), COUNT(DISTINCT Field3)
 FROM Table1
```

Output Is:

```
 COUNT(*) = 4; -- count all rows, even null/duplicates

 -- count only rows without null values on that field
 COUNT(Field1) = COUNT(Field2) = 3

 COUNT(Field3) = 2 
 COUNT(DISTINCT Field3) = 1 -- Ignore duplicates
```

Comment: I can make a row where all the fields are null? Is the case Microsoft was explaining in their documentation?

Comment: Yes, you can have all nulls in a row, as long all fields allow it. Would be very *weird*, but you can. Not sure about Microsoft intent on the documentation. This is something you have to learn after playing with the function. I have the same confusion when start.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just made a temp table and sure enough COUNT(*) included the null row. Having thought about it in this context, I think the more practical use of this and the point Microsoft is likely trying to make is grouping by a null value. For example if Field 2 and 3 in your example were not null and you grouped by Field 1.