# Include zero in COUNT with GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm looking to make a query in MySQL to list all the faculties and their number of students given the following table structure:

[image: mysql tables]

My query looks like:

```
SELECT `f`.`id`, `f`.`name`, COUNT(*) `total`
FROM `student` `s`
INNER JOIN `course` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `s`.`course_id`
LEFT JOIN `faculty` `f` ON `f`.`id` = `c`.`faculty_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`faculty_id`
ORDER BY `f`.`name`
```

And I'm getting this result:

[image: query result]

but I need to get all the faculties, even the ones without registered students.

If I use a LEFT JOIN with the `course` table I get the same results.

Comment: start from faculty table, then join to the other tables

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want all the faculties; your starting table for the JOIN should be the faculty table. Then do Left joins on the other table accordingly.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT `f`.`id`, `f`.`name`, COUNT(`s`.`id`) AS `total`
FROM `faculty` AS `f` 
LEFT JOIN `course` AS `c` ON `f`.`id` = `c`.`faculty_id` 
LEFT JOIN `student` AS `s` ON `c`.`id` = `s`.`course_id` 
GROUP BY `f`.`id`, `f`.`name` 
ORDER BY `f`.`name`
```

Comment: You need `COUNT(s.id)` otherwise you get 1 for NULL rows. Check this answer I give sometime ago.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679208/count-includes-null-values/40679371#40679371

Comment: `COUNT`  follow  ANSI standard  on all db. So yes, you need specify the field or will count rows instead of not null values. You can check this test example http://rextester.com/LAXC78995

Comment: this query is no way near ANSI standard annyway.. The select columns are not used in the GROUP BY unless MySQL could use functional dependency using the table indexes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to revese the query, your primary tables is faculties (or use right join) :
*important* - since you want to count cases of **zero** students you need to treat NULL values that might come up, joining the students table:

```
SELECT
`f`.`id`, `f`.`name`, SUM(IF(s.id IS NULL, 0,1) `total`
FROM
faculty f
LEFT JOIN course c ON `f`.`id` = `c`.`faculty_id`
LEFT JOIN student s ON `c`.`id` = `s`.`course_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`faculty_id` ORDER BY `f`.`name`
```

Comment: you must change to `SUM(IF(s.id IS NULL, 0,1))`