# how to get result of join also for records that dont have a joined record with another table?

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT suppliers.id, count(*) 
FROM suppliers
INNER JOIN supplier_addresses 
ON suppliers.id = supplier_addresses.supplier_id 
GROUP BY suppliers.id;
```

this gives my a table of supplierId and count of its addresses in the supplier_addresses table. But it only shows me suppliers that have at least 1 address.

I want to see in the result also count of 0 addresses...for example:

```
supplier.id | count(*)
1             3
2             0
3             1
4             9
```

in my query I dont see the second record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT suppliers.id, count(supplier_addresses.supplier_id ) 
FROM suppliers
LEFT JOIN supplier_addresses 
ON suppliers.id = supplier_addresses.supplier_id 
GROUP BY suppliers.id;
```

Comment: remember accept the answer with the green tick if solve your problem. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679208/count-includes-null-values/40679371#40679371) to see why I dont use `count(*)`