# How to get the average score of a department using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the average score of all department in my database, I have a query that get the average score of just one department, is there a way I can get the name of the department and their average score.
Lets assume I have 2 departments(Server and IT), The average of the server is the sum of all score of the people in that department divided by the total number of the department.

Here is a query I Have, but it's just the average of one department

```
SELECT SUM(RatingId)/(select COUNT(Id) from Employee where DepartmentId = 5) as Sums
FROM PerformanceReviewRatings pfr join
     Employee e
     on pfr.EmployeeId = e.Id join
     Department d
     on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
WHERE pfr.AppraisalId = 1009;
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`

```
SELECT e.DepartmentId, d.name, 
       SUM(RatingId)/COUNT(1) as Sums
  FROM PerformanceReviewRatings pfr
  JOIN Employee e
    ON pfr.EmployeeId = e.Id 
  JOIN Department d
    ON d.Id = e.DepartmentId
 WHERE pfr.AppraisalId = 1009
 GROUP BY e.DepartmentId, d.name
```

Comment: OP want the query works for every department, not just 5

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, thanks, I was concerning with formatting, lately realised.

Comment: This works fine for me, Thanks alot for your answer

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if I may ask, why the count(1)? I don't understand it

Comment: Is shortcut to indicate you are counting the number of rows. Same as `Count(id)`

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu I think you asked me. Not important what you put inside in this case, a constant like 1 or an asterisk. It's just an old habit.

Comment: `Count(1)` maybe give different result to `Count(*)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679208/count-includes-null-values/40679371#40679371

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you for the resource, but even testing with your link, we'll get the same results among asterisk and constant values. Since those constants are neither null, nor distinctly selected values : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7fec305461146f6b7505a50a5876aa6

Comment: I just saying you can get different result so have to be careful when say they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an employee gets only one rating, you don't need a subquery or a reference to the `Department` table:

```
SELECT e.DepartmentId,
       SUM(RatingId)/COUNT(*) as average_rating
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN
     PerformanceReviewRatings pfr
     ON pfr.EmployeeId = e.Id AND
        pfr.AppraisalId = 1009
GROUP BY e.DepartmentId;
```

If you only want the average of employees with ratings -- rather than one your question asks (which is to treat unrated employees as `0`s -- then:

```
SELECT e.DepartmentId, AVG(RatingId) as average_rating
FROM Employee e JOIN
     PerformanceReviewRatings pfr
     ON pfr.EmployeeId = e.Id
WHERE pfr.AppraisalId = 1009
GROUP BY e.DepartmentId
```

Comment: This work fine when I use just join instead of left join

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu . . . That is different from your question, then.  That is the average of only those employees that have ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AVG() function.

```
SELECT e.DepartmentId,
       AVG(RatingId) as average_rating
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN
     PerformanceReviewRatings pfr
     ON pfr.EmployeeId = e.Id AND
        pfr.AppraisalId = 1009
GROUP BY e.DepartmentId
```

Comment: This looks shorter, Thanks for your answer